# pdf pages in ps output file and eps figures in pdf output file

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, ps

I am facing the following issue: I have got several graphs in eps format and several pdf pages to insert into one ps document. Now, the eps figures are correctly included in my ps file, but the pdf pages are not. At the same time, when I produce not a ps file but a pdf file, the eps graphs are not included (my TeXnicCenter compiler does not recognise eps as valid format for graphics), but the pdf pages are included. I prefer to work with a ps output file, but will need to convert it at the end into a pdf file. Does anybody see what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

`pdflatex` doesn't support EPS graphics and the older `latex` (DVI mode) doesn't support PDF graphics. If you like to use both then you need to have your graphics in both formats. There are some tools and even packages like `epstopdf` which can help you here.